# Does the order of $f(x)$ divide the order of $x$ if $f$ is a group homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory

Suppose $f : G_1 \to G_2$ is a group homomorphism and let $x\in G$ be of finite order. Does the order of $f(x)$ divide the order of $x$?

Comment: Twice "the order **van** $\;x\;$" ...?

Comment: @DonAntonio Het copy and het paste

Comment: @HagenvonEitzen Lijkt goed te zijn...hehe.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, because $x^n=e_1$ implies $f(x)^n=f(x^n)=f(e_1)=e_2$.